# release or recylce the listView created item

Tags: android, android-listview

i have custom listView item with custom arrayAdapter
in adapter i use viewHolder to make listView scroll Smoothly , but when i scroll the list the item in listView is mixed
so i think should create the item again,now how can i release or recycle the previous created List item?

this is my getview code for arrayAdapter :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;
        //final ILSpeechBubble speechBubble;

        if(v == null)
        {
            inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            if(m_msg.get(position).Recieved == 0)
            {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_message_sent_row_template, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.spBubble = (ILSpeechBubble) v.findViewById(R.id.iLSpeechBubble1);

                holder.imgProfilePic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                holder.imgSend = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgMessageSent);

                holder.imgDeliverd = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgMessageDeliverd);
                holder.pbSending = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pbSendingMessage);

                holder.spBubble.isChache = false;
                v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_message_recieved_row_template, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.spBubble = (ILSpeechBubble) v.findViewById(R.id.iLSpeechBubble1);
                holder.imgProfilePic = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
                holder.spBubble.isChache = false;
                v.setTag(holder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            holder.spBubble.isChache = true;

            //return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occur due to recycling of views in list view .

- To release the previous views and to avoid recycling of view you can use the following code :

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ```
          View vi = null;
          convertView = null;
          vi = convertView;

          if (convertView == null) {

              vi = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);

              TextView name_textview = (TextView) vi
                      .findViewById(R.id.textEmp_id);

              name_textview.setText(slist_name.get(position));


          }
          return vi;

      }
  ```

Check this [link](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) ,it explains recycling of views and gives performance tips.

Comment: Don't worry. Recycler of the adapter should clear memory, when it notices that view is not used and app is close to it's limit.

Comment: it's don't and app crash, i analyze memory and the relativeLayout that mean my row view is very big